# How can I get the code of the function logisticregression() of sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression which is used in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, logistic-regression

I am using the function logisticregression() in jupyter notebook. I want to understand how that function works.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the file system location of the package `linear_model` that owns the class thus:

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> linear_model
<module 'sklearn.linear_model' from '/Users/awatters/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py'>
>>>
```

(The path will be different in your environment, of course.)  Then look in the `__init__.py` file at the path shown to find

```
from .logistic import (LogisticRegression, LogisticRegressionCV,
                   logistic_regression_path)
```

Then open the logistic.py in the same directory in an editor to find

```
class LogisticRegression(BaseEstimator, LinearClassifierMixin,
                     SparseCoefMixin):
    ...
```

Sadly the implementation is rather complex and hard to follow, but that's how to find it.